# show/hide list items in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have list of several items, i need to show them less first and show more after button click.. I have achieved that by some code.. But the list items are in "display:list-item" i need them in "display: inline/inline-block"

```js
$(function() {
  $('span').click(function() {
    $('#datalist li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
    if ($('#datalist li').length == $('#datalist li:visible').length) {
      $('span ').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul li:nth-child(n+3) {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="datalist">
  <li>dataset1</li>
  <li>dataset1</li>
  <li>dataset2</li>
  <li>dataset2</li>
  <li>dataset3</li>
  <li>dataset3</li>
  <li>dataset4</li>
  <li>dataset4</li>
  <li>dataset5</li>
  <li>dataset5</li>
</ul>
<span>readmore</span>
```

Comment: What's your question here?

Comment: @TreeNguyen he wants the li to be `display:inline-block` and not `display:list-item`

Comment: `.show()` uses the initial value of the element to show them, if you need something else you could do `.css( "display", "inline-block" )` instead

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen : Yess

Comment: Or toggle a class instead

Comment: @empiric : OMG... Simple Yet Thanks...

Comment: @empiric Also can anyone tell.. after reaching max length, it should show less in similar way upto certain length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a matter of changing your  code from:

```
$('#datalist li:hidden').slice(0, 2).show();
```

to

```
$('#datalist li:hidden').slice(0, 2).css('display','inline-block');
```

No need for extra classes. You can use classes if you want to add in CSS animations.

```js
$(function() {
  $('span').click(function() {
    $('#datalist li:hidden').slice(0, 2).css('display','inline-block');
    if ($('#datalist li').length == $('#datalist li:visible').length) {
      $('span ').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul li:nth-child(n+3) {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  display:inline-block;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="datalist">
  <li>dataset1</li>
  <li>dataset1</li>
  <li>dataset2</li>
  <li>dataset2</li>
  <li>dataset3</li>
  <li>dataset3</li>
  <li>dataset4</li>
  <li>dataset4</li>
  <li>dataset5</li>
  <li>dataset5</li>
</ul>
<span>readmore</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jquery's `.hide()` and `.show()`, use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` with a class that will toggle "display:none". That way you will revert back to `display:list-item` and not `block`/`inline-block`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('span').click(function() {
    $('#datalist li:hidden').slice(0, 2).removeClass('displayNone');
    if ($('#datalist li').length == $('#datalist li:visible').length) {
      $('span ').addClass('displayNone');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.displayNone {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="datalist">
  <li>dataset1</li>
  <li>dataset1</li>
  <li class="displayNone">dataset2</li>
  <li class="displayNone">dataset2</li>
  <li class="displayNone">dataset3</li>
  <li class="displayNone">dataset3</li>
  <li class="displayNone">dataset4</li>
  <li class="displayNone">dataset4</li>
  <li class="displayNone">dataset5</li>
  <li class="displayNone">dataset5</li>
</ul>
<span>readmore</span>
```